# mpl sequence and recursive code generation

Tags: c++, boost, recursion, metaprogramming

Lets say I have a MPL sequence `types` of length `N`
(e.g `boost::variant<int,string,double>` and the sequence of types `boost::variant::types` ):

I would like to recursively generate the following code for every possible index.
Precisely that the if statements run till `w==N`

```
void make(int w){

    if(w == 0){
      typename boost::mpl::at_c<types,0>::type t;
      // Some code
    }else if (w==1){
      typename boost::mpl::at_c<types,1>::type t;
      // Some code
    }...
     .
     .
     .
    }else if(w==N){
      typename boost::mpl::at_c<types,2>::type t;
      // Some code
    }else{
      // Runtime ERROR
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, since you're trying to do things at compiletime, your recursion will be compile time too. This immediately implies that you'll need a static (type) function that implements the recursion and the stop-condition.

If you want to achieve the code similar to what your pseudo-code show, you can use Boost Fusion, which contains algorithms that mimick the familiar runtime algorithms, like `boost::fusion::for_each`.

Fusion also has associative collections (`boost::fusion::map<...>`) that might fit your use case.

Comment: (posting this already for lack of time. I might find some time to elaborate with an example later)

Comment: that would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
template <int N>                                                                                                                                                                                          
void make(int w)                                                                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  if(w>N)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    make<-1>(w);                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  if(w==N)                                                                                                                                                                                                
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    typename boost::mpl::at_c<types, N>::type t;                                                                                                                                                    
    // Some code                                                                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  else                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    make<N-1>(w);                                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                         

template <>                                                                                                                                                                                               
void make<-1>(int w)                                                                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  // Runtime ERROR                                                                                                          
}
```

EDIT : Incorporated sehe's comment.

Comment: you could remove the duplication by calling `make<-1>(0)` if `(w>N)`